# Attention Model implementation Keras/Theano

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation

I am looking for an implementation of the attention models for Machine Translation using Keras/Theano. I have come across libraries like Groundhog, but I am looking for some basic implementation to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the AttentionSeq2Seq model from this library, it is built using Keras.
https://github.com/farizrahman4u/seq2seq